# EmberJS :reload/refresh view after creating new record while using jquery ajax instead of ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-view

I am creating a sample todo app using the jquery to talk to rest api instead of ember-data. The code is given below. I am able to list & add Todos using this code. But once I create a new record I have to refresh the browser to see the new record. how to i make the controller to reload the model?

Here is the Route

```
App.TodosRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 model: function() {
  return Ember.$.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/todos");
 }
});
```

Here is the Controller where I have the action to add new todos

```
App.TodosController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
actions: {
    addTodo: function(){
        var newTodo=this.get('newTodo');
        this.set('newTodo', '');
        Ember.$.post("http://localhost:3000/todos",{todo: newTodo}));
    }
}
});
```

Here is the template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="todos">
<legend>Todos</legend>
{{input type="text" id="new-todo" value=newTodo placeholder="Todo" action="addTodo" }}

<ul>
{{#each}}
<li><a href='#'>{{todo}}</a></li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add new todo in current routes model.

```
App.TodosController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
   actions: {
      addTodo: function(){
      var newTodo=this.get('newTodo');
      this.set('newTodo', '');
      self = this
      Ember.$.post("http://localhost:3000/todos",{todo:newTodo}).then(function(response)               {
         self.addObject(response);
     });
   }
 }
});
```